# could not to resolve the dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am unable to resolve the dependency on my system for google play location library.

The exact errors are

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0. Show Details Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0. Show Details Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0. Show Details Affected Modules: app

I hope `google()` should be enough for this and I am definitely not working in offline mode.

Any suggestions what could be wrong?[image: root level gradle file]

[image: app level gradle file]

Comment: There should be more info in the console when you try to sync the gradle.

Comment: post your build.gradle files

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-location/16.0.0 query I see it's part of google() repo, thus pls make sure you have google() as part of your repositories {} sections (under buildScript and allProjects of root build.gradle file).

Comment: Yes, Its available under buildScript and allProjects of build.gradle file

Comment: @Kaveri there is extremely simple test to make to verify. Just create empty project in android studio, no need to modify top level build.gradle file as it already has google() references. Then add `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'` to your app's build.gradle. Works! Your problem is apparently something different, or typo.

Comment: no it didn't. I have attached the top level and app level gradle files. please have a look

Comment: It says `debugUnitTest`. You are missing `testImplementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'` and `androidTestImplementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'`. But anyways I suspect it will also not work. You need to do what I posted above - start with clean project. There is some other mess going on in your existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved that error after 1 day !
There was a minor mistake. there was space entered in the library name.
After removing that, it was synced